# How Do I Manipulate the Area of a Double-Click for Windows Surface (SUR40) Table

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, sdk, pixelsense

I can't seem to find the topic of manipulating the size of the double-click area anywhere.  By this I mean that on the SUR40 and some programs I made, the double-click area is way to small for me and some others.  While we try double-clicking on a file, folder, item, etc. if we double click by a hair's width off from the first touchdown, the second touch is registered as a drag.  I was hoping if anyone would know how to manipulate this to enlarge the area of the click so we could double click without needing to have pin-point precision on both clicks.

I'm almost certain this could be coded in my programs (written in C#) but I haven't the faintest idea where/how to do this.  My only guess would be to create a new doubleclick event or class, but apart from that; I'm in the dark as to how I would code it.  I'm also hoping there is a way to manipulate this problem for the Windows 7 desktop as well.